# jenkins, what does fingerprint artifacts means?

Tags: jenkins, fingerprint, artifacts

**My understanding**

As far as I understood artifacts up to now, is that it was used to know if my project refers to an unfinished build task's artifacts.

**Problem**

I tried reading more (on jenkins site too) but I'm not sure I understand so easily what they do now. I know that when I promote a build, I can fingerprint artifacts. What does it mean then?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- **Artifacts** - anything produced *during* the build process.
- **Fingerprinting artifacts** - recording the **MD5 checksum** of selected artifacts.

You can then use the MD5 checksum to track a particular artifact back to the build it came from.

Comment: Thanks!! Now I get the difference I think. With the artifacts, I'd got no way to track where they came from?

Comment: Not unless you have a very well defined naming convention.

Answer (score 14):

Adding to @Slav answer, `Fingerprinting` help Jenkins in keeping track of ***which version of a file is used by which version of a dependency***.

Quoting an example and how it works from [Jenkins Page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Fingerprint):

**For example:**

- Suppose you have the `TOP` project that depends on the `MIDDLE` project, which in turn depends on the `BOTTOM` project.
- You are working on the `BOTTOM` project. The `TOP` team reported that `bottom.jar` that they are using causes an Null Pointer Exception, which you (a member of the BOTTOM team) thought you fixed in `BOTTOM #32`.
- Jenkins can tell you which `MIDDLE` builds and `TOP` builds are using (or not using) your `bottom.jar #32`.

**How does it work?**

The `fingerprint` of a file is simply a `MD5` checksum. Jenkins maintains a database of `md5sum`, and for each `md5sum`, Jenkins records which builds of which projects used. This database is updated every time a build runs and files are fingerprinted.

To avoid the excessive disk usage, Jenkins does not store the actual file. Instead, it just stores md5sum and their usages. These files can be seen in

```
$JENKINS_HOME/fingerprints
```