# What does the archiveArtifacts finger print = false mean?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am looking at the jenkins file configuration which says

```
post {
      always {
          archiveArtifacts artifacts: '*.*', fingerprint: false

      }
  }
```

what does the finger print mean here , How it is different from `fingerpring:true` parameter

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30985299/jenkins-what-does-fingerprint-artifacts-means

Answer (score 2):

Basically a fingerprint is just a hash (MD5) of your artifacts that let you track down the build that created the artifact.

[Source](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Fingerprint)